# Can't get row from DB, Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I want to set values from one row in table to second table and row in it. I am starting making controller method with this, because I am trying to get values firstly from view :

```
public function duplicate(Request $request, Proform $proform)
{
    var_dump($proform);
    var_dump($proform->id);

    $proform = DB::table('proforms')->where('id', $proform->id)->first();

    var_dump($proform);
}
```

I am getting values from view and on this line (FIRST)

```
 var_dump($proform);
```

I am getting this with id:

```
object(App\Proform)[1349]
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=24)
      0 => string 'proformnumber' (length=13)
      1 => string 'proformdate' (length=11)
      2 => string 'id' (length=2)
      3 => string 'selldate' (length=8)
      4 => string 'user_id' (length=7)
      5 => string 'paymentmethod' (length=13)
      6 => string 'paymentdate' (length=11)
      7 => string 'status' (length=6)
      8 => string 'comments' (length=8)
      9 => string 'city' (length=4)
      10 => string 'autonumber' (length=10)
      11 => string 'automonth' (length=9)
      12 => string 'autoyear' (length=8)
      13 => string 'name' (length=4)
      14 => string 'PKWIU' (length=5)
      15 => string 'quantity' (length=8)
      16 => string 'unit' (length=4)
      17 => string 'netunit' (length=7)
      18 => string 'nettotal' (length=8)
      19 => string 'VATrate' (length=7)
      20 => string 'grossunit' (length=9)
      21 => string 'grosstotal' (length=10)
      22 => string 'form_id' (length=7)
      23 => string 'currency_id' (length=11)
  public 'sortable' => 
    array (size=13)
      0 => string 'proformnumber' (length=13)
      1 => string 'proformdate' (length=11)
      2 => string 'id' (length=2)
      3 => string 'selldate' (length=8)
      4 => string 'user_id' (length=7)
      5 => string 'paymentmethod' (length=13)
      6 => string 'paymentdate' (length=11)
      7 => string 'status' (length=6)
      8 => string 'comments' (length=8)
      9 => string 'grosstotal' (length=10)
      10 => string 'nettotal' (length=8)
      11 => string 'form_id' (length=7)
      12 => string 'currency_id' (length=11)
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'table' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'keyType' => string 'int' (length=3)
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'withCount' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'exists' => boolean false
  public 'wasRecentlyCreated' => boolean false
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'changes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'casts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'classCastCache' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'dateFormat' => null
  protected 'appends' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'dispatchesEvents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'observables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'touches' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '*' (length=1)
```

But don't have idea why i am getting null on this (second)

```
var_dump($proform->id);
```

and after that

```
$proform = DB::table('proforms')->where('id', $proform->id)->first();
```

null on this (third)

```
var_dump($proform);



/home/laravel/web/laravel.swt101.eu/public_html/abonamenty/app/Http/Controllers/ProformController.php:33:null
/home/laravel/web/laravel.swt101.eu/public_html/abonamenty/app/Http/Controllers/ProformController.php:37:null
```

Firstly I am getting values from this view by pressing duplicate button:

```
   @extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Szczegóły abonamentu</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('proforms.index') }}"> Wstecz</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="col-md-4">
<form action="/duplicate" method="get">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="button" value="$proform->id" name="duplicate" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-prepend">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Wystaw fakturę</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>   



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Data wystawienia:</strong>
                {{ $proform->proformdate }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Kontrahent:</strong>
                {{ $proform->user_id }}
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Data sprzedaży:</strong>
                {{ $proform->selldate }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Termin płatności:</strong>
                {{ $proform->paymentdate }}
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Forma płatności:</strong>
                {{ $proform->paymentmethod }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Miejsce wystawienia:</strong>
                {{ $proform->city }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Status:</strong>
                {{ $proform->status }}
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Uwagi:</strong>
                {{ $proform->comments }}
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="pull-left" style="margin: 15px;">
                <h3>Pozycje proformy</h3>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Nazwa towaru lub usługi:</strong>
                {{ $proform->name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>PKWiU:</strong>
                {{ $proform->PKWIU }}
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Ilość:</strong>
                {{ $proform->quantity }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Jednostka:</strong>
                {{ $proform->unit }}
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Cena netto jednostki:</strong>
                {{ $proform->netunit }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Netto razem:</strong>
                {{ $proform->nettotal }}
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Stawka VAT:</strong>
                {{ $proform->VATrate }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Brutto jednostka:</strong>
                {{ $proform->grossunit }}
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Brutto razem:</strong>
                {{ $proform->grosstotal }}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endsection
<p class="text-center text-primary"><small>Artplus 2020</small></p>
```

This is my router:

```
 ...
    Route::get('/duplicate', 'ProformController@duplicate');
  ...
```

Comment: can you post the route here.

Comment: Yes, @aimme is correct, I am assuming you haven't configured your route-model binding correctly. ```route/to/duplicate/{proform}```  if you have not customized your route-model binding, then ```{proform}``` needs to be the id of the model you are trying to resolve in the route.

Comment: I edited post and added routes.

Comment: which route is that?

Comment: Route::get('/duplicate', 'ProformController@duplicate');

Comment: You need ```Route::get('/duplicate/{proform}', 'ProformController@duplicate');``` And when you make a request to the route you will need to call ie) ```/duplicate/1```

Comment: After that I've got error 404
Route::get('/duplicate/{proform}', 'ProformController@duplicate');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your route name should match the model for the model to be injected. In this case the route should have a `proform` argument. In your case model is not bound and an empty intance is returned.

if it is duplicate as @Kurt said your route should be like

```
Route::get('/duplicate/{proform?}', 'ProformController@duplicate');
```

and in this case it should be optional.

But I would recommend you change it like following. create a post route for duplicate post and use the get route for showing form

```
Route::get('/duplicate/{proform}', 'ProformController@duplicateForm')->name('proforms.duplicateForm');
Route::post('/duplicate', 'ProformController@duplicatePost')->name('proforms.duplicate');
```

controller

```
public function __construct(Proform $proform)
{
   $this->proform = $proform;
}

public function duplicateForm(Request $request, Proform $proform)
{
    return view('the form view here', ['proform' => $proform]);
}


public function duplicatePost(Request $request)
{
    $proform = $this->proform->findOrFail($request->duplicate);

    //something like this
    $duplicated = $this->proform->create($proform->toArray());

    dump($duplicated);
}
```

duplicate form

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<form action="{{ route('proforms.duplicate') }}" method="POST">
@csrf

<div class="input-group">
<input type="button" value="{{$proform->id}}" name="duplicate" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-prepend">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Wystaw fakturę</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Additionally, in Laravel you can use following functions instead of `var_dump()`

```
dd() //die and dump, same as var_dump();exit;
dump() //dump,  same as var_dump();
```

Comment: After that I've got error 404
Route::get('/duplicate/{proform}', 'ProformController@duplicate');

Comment: I have updated the answer. it is because you are using same get route and one is trying it to be optional.

Comment: updated again with dependency injection assuming that you have proform model.

Comment: you also had this issue. fixed now value="{{$proform->id}}"

Comment: you can use dd() and dump() instead of var_dump

Comment: I added second part of the code but now have got this error:
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: you should have this route too. Route::get('/duplicate/{proform}', 'ProformController@duplicateForm')->name('proforms.duplicateForm'); to show the form

Comment: also have you changed the form method to post method="POST"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218975/discussion-between-aimme-and-piotr-switlicki).